# Ping command works by itself but not in command file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, ping

This particular line of code is one I found previously online, and I've used it quite a bit.  It pings a given server by name or address, and adds a date and time stamp to the output, which is sent to a text file.

It works flawlessly if I copy and paste it into a command line, but in a command file (.cmd) it does not work.

The only thing I knew myself to do was give the variable double "%%" signs, which I did.

Here is my code:

```
CLS

@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:start

    set /p server=Enter the server name you wish to run a continuous ping of:

    echo %server%

    if exist \\%server%\c$ goto ping
    echo THIS SERVER IS OFFLINE OR DOES NOT EXIST
    echo VERIFY NAME ENTERED AND TRY AGAIN
    pause

    goto start

:ping

    echo %server%

ping -t %server%|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 %server%>nul" >C:\%server%_ping.txt

:end
```

Comment: Ignore the "echo %server%" stuff, I added that just to trace where I was in the code.  It's useless and has no relevance to the problem.

Comment: Also, I do get output to the text file, but it is ONLY the date and time stamp.  I do not get ping results showing in the text output.

Comment: Not sure, but I guess the `pause` commands might "swallow" the resulting `ping` text...

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I removed that and it made no difference though.

Comment: What's the infinite `for /L` loop for?

Comment: Well it's supposed to be a continuous ping.  Also, I can copy out that single line, paste it into a command prompt, replace %server% with an actual server name, and remove one of the percent signs from the variable in the FOR loop, and it works flawlessly. I just don't know why it won't in a .CMD file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable the delayed variable expansion in your batch file, because the subshell of pipe is using delayed expansion which is instructed by `cmd /v`.

Enabling the delayed expansion in your batch causes the delayed variables to be resolved before the subshell begins execution.

You need to change `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion`

Currently your batch file itself does not need delayed variable expansion, but if it needed, then it should disable the delayed expansion just before executing the pipe command.

Comment: Thank you!  Makes perfect sense.  Thank you for opening my eyes to this.  Should have paid more attention to the switches for CMD.  It works now.  Consider this solved.

Comment: Alternative: escape every (quoted) `!` by `^!`, so delayed expansion can be enabled in the hosting batch file...